# Local host not reachable by using nodeport service in docker desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, desktop, wsl-2

I'm Using docker desktop . When I am using nodeport as a service the application is not accessible for the localhost.

Tried kubectl get SVC and the service is nodeport only

Comment: Which OS are you using? can you paste the url that are you trying to access? if you run kubectl port-forward service/<svc_name> <your_localhost_port>:<svc_port> can you access to the service?

Comment: I am using WSL2 on windows . Port forwarding too it's not working . Previously It was working but suddenly now it stopped working .

Comment: Ok, in that case the NodePort are exposed on the linux env and it has a different IP address, you can get the IP address opening a bash and running `ip a s` and getting the eth0 interface ip address, or in windows run 
wsl -- ip -o -4 -json addr list eth0 `
| ConvertFrom-Json `
| %{ $_.addr_info.local } `
| ?{ $_ }

And access to that IP address and mapped nodeport